# Maven Dependency Issue for json-schema-validator

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-mail, json-schema-validator

I am using 2 dependencies in my pom.xml.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
    </dependency>
```

But for json-schema-validator, javax.mail (version 1.4.3) is a dependency already. When my application is launched, my mail service (version 1.5.0-b01) doesn't work at all. But when I remove the json-schema-validator dependency, mail service works perfectly fine. Can someone please help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your project and look at the dependency tree using :

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building com.greg 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ example-jar ---
[INFO] com.greg:example-jar:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.github.fge:json-schema-validator:jar:2.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:jar:6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.fge:json-schema-core:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.fge:uri-template:jar:0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.github.fge:msg-simple:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.github.fge:btf:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.fge:jackson-coreutils:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mozilla:rhino:jar:1.7R4:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.mail:mailapi:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:4.6:compile
[INFO] \- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.5.0-b01:compile
[INFO]    \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.819 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-16T08:01:10+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/174M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I am guessing you want to make sure you get the latest version of javax.mail

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
         <artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If json-schema-validator depends on javax.mail:mailapi, that's a long since obsolete artifact.  Someone should report that to the owners of json-schema-validator.  Also, javax.mail:mail:1.5.0-b01 is in intermediate build of an obsolete artifact.  The [current version of JavaMail is com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.6](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release).